# Show an image on whole page

Tags: asp.net

How can i show an image on whole page when user click a button?
(means i have several controls on page and want to show this image over all of them)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? It is not clear what exactly you mean, so an example would help us understand the question.

Comment: i want to add data to database and want to show an image when user click button until datas add to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this line in button click event

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "key", "javascript: document.body.background = 'Untitled.jpg'; document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat'; document.body.style.backgroundPosition = '300px 300px'; ", true);
```

Comment: nothing happen when i click on button

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad : See my updated answer. Just remove `style`.

Comment: it works,but if i have an image with size 40*40 with this code it repeated.how to solve this?

Comment: with this code doesn't show image

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad : Are you there? This code is tested one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18049/discussion-between-jams-and-sajjjjjjad)

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a [Modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), there are some great jQuery plugins for that. I really like one called [Reveal](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin).

To do it yourself. Set a "position: absolute" and a "z-index" that is higher than your other elements on a div, and trigger it to show/hide with javascript and you should be fine.

Comment: thank you,it's great.but just one question : how can i control it from code behind?(means i can show and close it from code)

Comment: I would control it using javascript and sending an ajax request instead of performing a codebehind call.

Comment: i don't know how to do it can you explain more?